If a non-provisional application claims multiple provisional applications, will there be multiple priority dates?
For example:

Provisional A is filed on January 1, 2024 (with content X).
Provisional B is filed on June 1, 2024 (adding content Y).
When you file the non-provisional application that claims both Provisional A and Provisional B, the priority date for content X will be January 1, 2024, and the priority date for content Y will be June 1, 2024.

Is the above correct?
Or can all content, from both the provisional applications, claim priority from the first, i.e. Jan 1st in the example.


Is the above correct?

Yes. It's per claim. If a claim is supported by the Jan 1 provisional it will not be possible to reject it based on prior art that has a date later than Jan 1. Claims that find adequate support in the Jun 1 provisional cannot be rejected based on prior art that has a date later than Jun 1.

Or can all content, from both the provisional applications, claim priority from the first, i.e. Jan 1st in the example.

No. This would only encourage inventors to file half-baked provisionals in the hope that they could fill in any missing detail later.
